# DataStax Ops Center does not show nodes

Tags: cassandra, datastax, opscenter

Though DataStax OpsCenter Web UI is running, I could not find any nodes.

The following entries are in log: 
Stopping repair service
OpsCenter starting up

Any help would be appreciated.

I have installed it on two laptops ... it is running on one laptop without any issue.
I have Windows 64 bit professional.

**Edit:**
I ran nodetool status and got :

```
Starting NodeTool
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  807.53 KB  256     100.0%  9abddff9-5a77-4029-a06f-fd2ec878018b  rack1
```

Attached here copy of opscentered.log https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9RdLoIZyowGTUI5UUZaLWtobkk/edit?pli=1

Attached here screenshot of OpsCenter Dashboard https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RdLoIZyowGZ0hCNTZrVWhwelk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you run 'nodetool status'?

Comment: Usually this is a symptom of OpsCenter not being able to connect to your cluster via thrift.  Do you see any errors in opscenterd.log indicating that?  Or any other obvious errors there?  If you are able to link to the full opscenterd.log and any screenshots of what you're seeing in the UI, that would be helpful  -- *Edit* I see you are running OpsCenter 4.1.4.  Are you able to upgrade to 5.0.0 to rule out any bugs that may have already been fixed?

Comment: Did the upgrade help? It's interesting that it is showing some cluster statistics but not the node.

Comment: I would recommend going to OpsCenter 5.0.1 at least. There is a known issue with OpsCenter 5.0.0 with some latency graphs showing incorrect values.